# Conflict between FetchedResultsController and GDC for images downloaded from net into a table view?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I tried to build a table view with help of coredata and FetchedResultsController (info from coredata is take it with an API from a server), each cell from table has a image view which load images from net asynchronous with GCD (also I tried and with SDWebImage) in method
"tableView:tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath", the problem appear when I make another request for more records (for example first time I have 50 records, and when I do a new request and save it in core data the images are no more correct associated with article or disappear on scrolling)  I believe because the results from fetchedResultsController are sorted in function of time.
My code:

```
NewsFeed *singleFeed = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
NLNewsFeedCell *cell = (NLNewsFeedCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil)
{
    NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"NewsFeedCell" owner:self options:nil];
    cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    cell.lblTextContain.numberOfLines = 0;
}
    dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0ul);
    dispatch_async(queue, ^(void) {
        NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:singleFeed.urlPicture]];

        UIImage* image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];
        if (image) {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                cell.imgPicture.image = image;
                [cell setNeedsLayout];
            });
        }
    });
```

}

Any suggestion, how can solve this problem?
Thanks and sorry for misspelling.

Comment: Is the issue related to source data or to cell reuse?  Your code doesn't check the cell hasn't been reused before setting the image.

Comment: @Wain the problem is related on the cell reuse.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, check for reused cells:

`UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cellIdentifier"];`

If the cell is `nil`, create new one. If is not `nil` use the existing one.

Second, I would suggest that you create a custom cell that handles the download of the image with the possibility of cancel the download or ignore the download.

Your problem is caused by the fact that the download is completed after the cell is loaded and it's possible that the download is completed for the cell that is not visible anymore.

You could use [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) or any other async image loading library that supports download cancel and in the custom cell's `-(void)prepareForReuse` method (which is called before the cell is reused) you can cancel the old download operation so when the cell is loaded it will use the image from the last download operation.

Comment: Or at least check for the cell being at the original index path before setting the image.

Comment: ok, let me check this was also my initial hunch, the fetchedResultsController is updated in continuous and from this reason it will be a problem with caching

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing the rest of the code, I am noticing something probably wrong if this is executed within the classic `cellForRowAtINdexPath`.

Every time the cell is displayed you are always downloading image from the net, and this can happens many times depending on how many times you scroll UITableView up and down. This can results in unnecessary network operations, if you haven't implemented any URLCache, or worst, if the server responds with no-cache.  You should build a kind of local downloader which load images asynchronously only once and store in a cache, and block any subsequent requests of the same resource.

Regard your problem, don't forget that cells are reused. This means that the UITableCell is created and refilled again with new data.
I found very useful to implement `prepareForReuse` in my custom class cell to clean any resources inherited for previous Entities. Otherwise, unless download is finished and images replaced, you will see old images.

Comment: @Leonardo I know about problem related of caching, from this reason I used to a moment a library "SDWebImage" (but same problems like on GCD), and also I clean up the the resources in method what you recommended and still nothing.